# Finding a best fit curve and plotting it

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fitting

I have a list as shown below:

```
m01 = {{250, 0.083121}, {200, 0.0888446}, {150, 0.0992422}, {100, 0.121567}, {50, 0.186825}}
```

I'm new to Mathematica, and would like to know how can I do these jobs:

1- How can I can plot it with `ListPlot` and make minimal formations on it?

2- How do I fit a curve on it? Witch command I use? How to put the curve plot together with the points?

Comment: try opening the docs and typing "best fit" (and follow the trail)

Comment: This is not a free consultancy service. You have to demonstrate that you expended some of your own effort before people are likely to help you.

Comment: I tried to make some changes in the question to make it more generic. I think that now It's a good questions for new users (I remember me having this problems when I started use MMA).

Comment: @Murta what do you mean "make minimal formations on it"?

Comment: Like add, title, colors, range and so on. I don't know if it was a good ask! ..  Suggestions? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one model.

```
m01 = {{250, 0.083121}, {200, 0.0888446}, {150, 0.0992422}, {100, 0.121567}, {50, 0.186825}};
model = LinearModelFit[m01, {x^-1}, x];

p2 = Plot[model@x, {x, 0, 250}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
p1 = ListPlot[m01, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.025]}];

Show[p2,p1
  ,PlotLabel -> Column[
     Style[#, Bold, 15]& /@ {"Adjusted R Squared", model["AdjustedRSquared"]}
     ,Alignment->Center]
  ,PlotRange -> {{0, 250}, All}
  ,AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
  ,Frame -> True
  ,Epilog ->
    Inset[Style[Framed@Normal@model, Bold, 14], Scaled[{0.95, 0.95}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]
]
```

You get:

[image]

and it has a nice R2, too.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Murta. I tried FittedModel with exponential function. when I plot it with listplot, it was near the x axis. This is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SE! I made some updates in the presentation form. Make good use.

Answer (score 2):

my curve is smooth too, and my R^2 is 0.999997

```
model = NonlinearModelFit[data, ( a/x + b + c Sin[x/d]), {a, {b, 25}, c, d}, {x}, 
        Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt", MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

Here is the plot (*added by s0rce*)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you add a plot including the fit line? I'll upvote it, if you do.

Comment: Either, create the plot, save it somewhere, and use the sixth button from the left in the edit window to bring up the file upload dialog. Or, you could use [Szabolcs uploader](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32/52).

Comment: Why did you choose to add a sinusoidal compoenent to the fit? It is very small `c = 0.00436027` and The adjusted R2 only increases from 0.999982 to 0.999997. Could you explain this to improve your answer? The oscillation seems odd.

Comment: I added the plot for you.

Comment: @s0rce I was trying to teach him to fish ...

Comment: @rcollyer, I know but it was too funny looking once I made it I had to put it up there. I can remove if you want.

Comment: @s0rce no, don't. He can look at the edit you made to see what was done. Besides, it is funny looking.

Comment: @sOrce & rcollyer, thanks for adding the plot for me, I'm still having trouble with the image thing, I think that somhow some of the buttons arn't showing up for me. As for the curve, I was just playing around thought that this curve would demonstrate one of the almost unlimited possibilities of curves that fit the question and also MM's almost unlimited versatility.

Comment: Well..this sin functions make no sense. To much parameters for a small number of points, it's a overfiting problem... If it's just for fun so ok.